# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freezes a lot with windows 10 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, freeze

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a machine with windows 10 dual boot configuration. I notice frequent freezes while using applications like chrome, eclipse etc and also while switching between programs. Any suggestions around the same ?

Answer (score 0):

GNOME-shell 3.26.2 has a documented memory leak w/ lags and freezes, as shown in  [Bugzilla](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1672297) and the [GNOME bug tracking forum](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/64).  One user found [disabling animations helps but does not solve the issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787983).

Until then, you may consider using a [different flavor](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of 18.04 LTS such as [Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ububntu Kyliin, or Ubuntu Mate](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/04/ubuntu-flavors-18-04-release-download-features).  They do not have this problem, which is limited to GNOME-shell .

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know if kubuntu or all these versions are stable and don't have such issues?

Comment: @NitinSaxena All these flavors are stable. Every flavor has different shell or desktop environment.

Comment: I think switching to desktop environment other than gnome, like unity might help.

Comment: And, should you find this a viable solution, please click on the checkmark above at left to show this solved the problem for you. Other folks can look for that checkmark to filter for solutions.

Comment: for now, I removed the windows. Under observation now. But I noticed memory management is also seems to be an issue(may be to me). I have 4gb RAM and when its almost full system crashes or freezes to a state where hard shutdown is the only option left.

Comment: Removing Windows will not resolve any memory issues within Ubuntu, it just possibly makes for disk space open.